# IIS rewrite rule not matching -- setting up reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-7.5

This seems to be like the simplest of thing which I am unable to resolve.

I want to rewrite URL if it contains the string **extFlow**, to a different host.

```
http://site1/extFlow/Testsvc/GetData/?val=1
```

to

```
http://site2/extFlow/Testsvc/GetData/?val=1
```

I have tried all rules eg:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="Reverse Proxy to external" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="extFlow/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://site2/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

If I just match with (.*) then the rewrite happens.

I am not able to match even with * match url="extFlow"

What am I missing?

Comment: Is site2 hosted on the same machine ?

Comment: Yes for testing purpose I have both sites on same machine, but on a different port.  But these sites will be on different hosts in live environemnt

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement "Yes for testing purpose I have both sites on same machine, but on a different port", I think that's what is breaking your rule. Let me disintegrate and explain it.

- Observe how you have "extFlow" in both your URL's.
- Let's assume a request came in for
  "http://site1/extFlow/Testsvc/GetData/?val=1". The URL rewrite rule
  is hit and its rewrites it to
  "http://site2/extFlow/Testsvc/GetData/?val=1".
- Since this new URL also hits the same machine and even it has
  "extFlow" in it, the rule will be triggered once again and again and 
  again.
- So indirectly you are triggering an indefinite loop here.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am writing the rules in the web.config of site1. If I write the rules in "Default website", then the rule works :)